# How to NOT replace a word with an asterisk at the end?

Tags: bash, sed

I specify the command below to find strings that match EXACTLY `returnType` but the command also searches for strings that contain `returnType*` and performs the substitution.

`sed -e "/\<returnType\>/ s/word1/word2/" input.cpp`

How do I make the command so that it ignores `returnType*`? Why is it performing a substitution on a `returnType*`?

I'm trying to distinguish between regular `returnType` and pointer `returnType*`, and it's not working.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: But the `\<`  and `\>` match a `<` and `>` also, is that intended? Also the \ backslashes are ignored in this context, I think.

Comment: `*` counts as a word boundary, so it matches `\>`

Comment: Of course `\<returnType\>` matches exactly `returnType*`. Why wouldn't it? You asked `sed` to select those lines which contain the word `returnType`, and it obeyed you; `sed` does not know C (or any other programming language), so it has no idea what a pointer is. If you want to select those lines which contain the word `returnType` *not followed by an asterisk* you may try `/\<returnType\>\($\|[^*]\)`, possibly with more trickery to accound for possible spaces between `returnType` and `*`.

Comment: You could do `sed -e '/returnType\*/! {/\<returnType\>/ s/word1/word2/}'`

Comment: Note that you're using a gnu extension to have `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries. (I think it's a gnu extension that makes that work, anyway.  It's hard to keep track.  Anyway, it's non-standard)

Answer (score 1):

Append '[^*]' to the pattern to require anything but *.

```
sed -e "/\<returnType\>[^*]/ s/word1/word2/"
```

Note '*' not having special meaning as part of bracket expression.